# Where to add Firebase Database Reference in iOS Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I'm setting up a realtime database through Firebase and am confused where to put the following line of code:

```
self.ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
```

These are the instructions I'm following: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start

[image]

Comment: It says, once you've initialized Firebase, create a reference, which means, it should be the next line in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOption`. Whereas `ref` should be your class-property.

Comment: Thanks @AdilSoomro. How do I set up the class property?

Comment: Here's apple documentation on using properties in Obj-C [Encapsulating Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html)

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I added (at)property FIRDatabaseReference *ref; to the (at)interface section and it looks to be working.

Comment: That's cool to know. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address this, I added the following line under (at)interface in my App Delegate:

```
@property FIRDatabaseReference *ref;
```

Then I could add the following under didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
self.ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
```

Answer (score 3):

Its simple, Just Add following line in your AppDelegate.h

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) FIRDatabaseReference * ref;// Property
```

After adding,In your AppDelegate.m didFinishLaunchingWithOption 
Replace

```
self.ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
```

With

```
_ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
```

Problem Solved..
:)